# Disable all horizontal scrollbars in Cypress

Tags: css, cypress

Is there a way to apply a style to all elements in Cypress?  Like one would do with the star selector:

```
* {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I need this for visual regression snapshots, because of scrollbars that appear, and haven't been able to find something simple and elegant in Cypress.  Currently doing something like this:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="some-tag"]').invoke('css', 'overflow-x', 'hidden');
```

But of course this isn't great, because every element that has scrollbars has to be targetted and set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the DOM just before any screenshot is taken by using *onBeforeScreenshot* and *onAfterScreenshot* callbacks. This will hide the scrollbar on the element the screenshot command was called on, and restore it afterwards:

```
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
    onBeforeScreenshot($el) {
        $el.css('overflow', 'hidden');
    },

    onAfterScreenshot($el, props) {
        $el.css('overflow', 'auto');
    },
});
```

You can put this function in *support/index.js* file since it is loaded before any test files.

Note: if you just call `cy.screenshot()` then the `$el` will be the `document` and you can use `.find(<selector>)` command to get any child elements within the page.

Works great with [cypress-visual-regression](https://github.com/mjhea0/cypress-visual-regression) plugin.

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/screenshot-api#Change-the-DOM-using-onBeforeScreenshot-and-onAfterScreenshot